# Ember.js: getting data from back-end using JSONAPIAdapter - doesn't work

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js, adapter

I'm trying to get data from remote backend api. As I followed the docs, (https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/models/customizing-adapters/), 'The JSONAPIAdapter is smart enough to determine the URLs it communicates with based on the name of the model.' So I generated the Route, the Model and the Adapter.

Here's the code of the Adapter:

```js
//app/adapters/app.js

import Ember from 'ember';
import JSONAPIAdapter from 'ember-data/adapters/json-api';
import JSONAPISerializer from 'ember-data/serializers/json-api';

export default JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  ajax: Ember.inject.service(),
  host: 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie',
  headers: {
    'API_KEY': '72b56103e43843412a992a8d64bf96e9'
  },
  pathForType: function(type) {
   return Ember.String.underscore(type);
  },
  serializer: JSONAPISerializer.extend({
   primaryKey: 'id',

   serializeId: function(id) {
    return id.toString();
   }
  })
});
```

The code of the Model

```js
//app/models/movie.js

import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';
// import { belongsTo, hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default Model.extend({
 poster_path: attr('string'),
 adult: attr('boolean'),
 overview: attr('string'),
 release_date: attr('string'),
 genre_ids: attr('array'),
 original_title: attr('string'),
 original_language: attr('string'),
 title: attr('string'),
 backdrop_path: attr('string'),
 popularity: attr('number'),
 vote_count: attr('number'),
 video: attr('boolean'),
 vote_average: attr('number')
});
```

The Router of the app:

```js
//app/router.js

import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('movies', {
    path: '/'
  });
});

export default Router;
```

And the code of the Route:

```js
//app/routes/movies.js

import Ember from 'ember';
import Movie from 'search-movies/models/movie';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
 model() {
  return this.store.findAll('movie');
 }
});
```

But if I run the app, I get the error of 404:

`Error while processing route: movies Ember Data Request GET /movies returned a 404`

I guess, the store service can't get the models. But why? I've generated the Adapter. Do I need to import it somewhere? Or what? Why this structure doesn't work? Need help.

Comment: What's URL Ember is trying to hit and what URL is your API endpoint for movies hosted on?

Comment: Without seeing the url that ember-data is requesting, I would guess that your host is wrong in the adapter. It should be `http://api.themoviedb.org.` Ember-data should generate the path. Take a look at your network tab to see whats going on.

Comment: None of these code-snippets are runnable, so it really just makes the post less readable. Your indentation was a bit hard to read as well. If you can ensure that it's readable, you'll get less people bouncing away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You located your adapter under `app/adapters/app.js` but the application adapter should be under `app/adapters/application.js` or `app/application/adapter.js`.

Since your adapter seems specific for the `movie` model I would consider to place it as an model specific adapter under `app/adapters/movie.js` or `app/movie/adapter.js`.